# Is there a javascript function for indexing only the textcontent (as opposed to raw code) within in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, text, slice

I have some text within a div separated by line breaks, for example:

```
<div id="myDiv">abcd<br>hij<br>klmnop</div>
```

The issue is that `document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML.slice(0,5)` returns `abcd<`, but I need it to return `"abcd<br>"`. I am trying to get a substring that maintains the line breaks but treats them as a single index instead of four distinct characters of `<br>`.

I could write a function that reads in the entire string, replaces all instances of `<br>` with a single character string such as `@`, then use the `slice()` function to get the substring I need, and finally replace all instances of `@` with `<br>`. But is there a much more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: No, `document.getElementById("myDiv").value` would return `undefined`.

Comment: @Pointy thank you! I edited the question to say `document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML`

Comment: it's better to use `substr(start,length)` function . `document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML.substr(0,5)`

Comment: I would use a regex for this

Comment: I think the way you described it in your final paragraph is ideal. `document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML.replace(/<br>/g, "\n").substr(0, 5).replace(/\n/g, "<br>")`. It seems verbose, but it does what you need.

Answer (score 1):

matches all strings with `<br>` at the end or end of string.

```js
console.log(
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML.match(/(.*?<br>|.+?$)/g)
)
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">abcd<br>hij<br>klmnop</div>
```

another option is to traverse the childNodes and extract text nodes and handle other dom elements.  I've created a simple map of childNodes that extracts wholeText (for text nodes) or the HTML.

```js
console.log(
[...document.getElementById("myDiv").childNodes].map(x=>x.wholeText||x.outerHTML)
)
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">abcd<br>hij<br>klmnop</div>
```